# Setting an interval on do / while from 5 to 5

Tags: php

I've made a repeat region with dreamweaver and the result is this:

```
<div>
  <?php do { ?>
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['imagemUrl']; ?>" />
      <h2><a href="projecto.php?projecto=<?php echo $row_Recordset1['idProj'];"><?php echo $row_Recordset1['titleProj']; ?></a></h2>
    </div>
  <?php while ($row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1)); ?>
</div>
```

No problem here, it works fine.

The thing is, I'm trying to use only 5 slides for each page, something like this:

```
<div>
 <div class="page">
  <?php do { ?>      
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['imagemUrl']; ?>" />
      <h2><a href="projecto.php?projecto=<?php echo $row_Recordset1['idProj'];"><?php echo $row_Recordset1['titleProj']; ?></a></h2>
    </div>
  <?php
    $i = 0;
    $r = $i % 5;
    $i++;
    if ( $r == 0 ) {
    ?>
    </div> <!-- closes div.page -->
    <div class="page"> <!-- adds a new div.page -->
    <? } ?>
  <?php while ($row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1)); ?>
</div>
```

It's obviously not working, but hopefully you'll see what I'm trying to reach.

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE:

The result i get is:

```
<div class="page">
 <div class="slide">...</div>
 <div class="slide">...</div>
 <div class="slide">...</div>
 <div class="slide">...</div>
 <div class="slide">...</div>
 <div class="slide">...</div>
 <div class="slide">...</div>
 <div class="slide">...</div>
</div>
```

I would like it to be:

```
<div class="page">
 <div class="slide">...</div>
 <div class="slide">...</div>
 <div class="slide">...</div>
 <div class="slide">...</div>
 <div class="slide">...</div>
</div>
<div class="page">
 <div class="slide">...</div>
 <div class="slide">...</div>
 <div class="slide">...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: what do you mean by "not working"? it closes that div on the very first iteration?

Comment: how about using a `for loop`?

Comment: @mishu i've updated, hope it answers your question

Comment: @jcdavid how does that work? please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting $i to 0 on every iteration. Place the `$i = 0` before the do-while loop.

You should probably also place `$i++` before `$r = $i % 5;` to get the result you require.

EDIT: You're also missing a closing brace before your while statement (typo?)

Hence, the complete code:

```
<div>
    <div class="page">
    <?php
    $i = 0;
    do { ?>      
        <div class="slide">
            <img src="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['imagemUrl']; ?>" />
            <h2><a href="projecto.php?projecto=<?php echo $row_Recordset1['idProj'];?>"><?php echo $row_Recordset1['titleProj']; ?></a></h2>
        </div>
    <?php
        $i++;
        $r = $i % 5;
        if ( $r == 0 ) {
    ?>
        </div> <!-- closes div.page -->
        <div class="page"> <!-- adds a new div.page -->
    <?php 
        } 
    } while ($row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1)); ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would loop through 5 times adding a new `<div>content</div>` to the variable `$html`. You can then echo the variable in your html body.

```
$html = "";

for ($i=0;$i<5;$i++) {
    $html .= "<div class=\"page\">". $content[$i] . "</div>\n";
}
```

Additions:

```
<?PHP

while ($row_Recordset = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1)) {

    $html .= "<div class='page'>\n";

    for ($i=0;$i<5;$i++) {
        $html .= "<div class='slide'>". $row_Recordset[$i]['column'] . "</div>\n";
    }

    $html .= "</div>\n";
}
?>
```

This code will loop through the recordset populating `$html` on each iteration. Try `echo $html` and you will have an output structured as you want.

Answer (score 0):

the piece you gave is not a valid php code.
the line here:

```
<h2><a href="projecto.php?projecto=<?php echo $row_Recordset1['idProj'];"><?php echo $row_Recordset1['titleProj']; ?></a></h2>
```

opens a php tag without closing it before the next one you open.. so a first step would be to change that line to

```
<h2><a href="projecto.php?projecto=<?php echo $row_Recordset1['idProj'];?>"><?php echo $row_Recordset1['titleProj']; ?></a></h2>
```

also you missed closing a block, here:

```
<? } ?>
```

you should close both the if and the do/while block (so another })

another problem is the fact that on every step you change $i to 0, so every time $r will be 0 also

so in conclusion: take your problems step by step as you have more than one

Comment: Those problems were typing mistakes, sorry bout that. $i = 0 was in the wrong place, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
 <div class="page">
<?php for ($i = 0; $row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1); $i++) { ?>
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['imagemUrl']; ?>" />
      <h2><a href="projecto.php?projecto=<?php echo $row_Recordset1['idProj']; ?>"><?php echo $row_Recordset1['titleProj']; ?></a></h2>
    </div>
  <?php if ( $i % 5 == 0 && $i ) { ?>
    </div> <!-- closes div.page -->
    <div class="page"> <!-- adds a new div.page -->
  <?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
  </div>
</div>
```